# Adding HTML and iFrames to Markdown JS

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm using [Markdown JS](https://github.com/cadorn/markdown-js) to convert Markdown for my CMS.

I need to allow embedding of iFrames in the text body.

How can I do this?